# How to load next chess game page in php

Tags: php

I have http://communitychessclub.com/games-nu.php with a game scores table.

And I want the user to be able to scroll from game to game. The games were sequentially numbered, but many had to be removed.

So instead of "game1001.php" and "game1002.php", I have "game1203.php" and "game1007.php" The problem is that each game has L-R icons for scrolling forward and backward to other games.

```
<?php $file = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]; $game = substr($file,11,4);

$filename = '../games.csv'; if (file_exists($filename)) 
{$last_mod = filemtime($filename);
if (!($games_date == $last_mod)) 
{$games_date = $last_mod; $lines = count(file($filename));}} 

if ($game==1001){$game_prev=1000+$lines;} else {$game_prev = $game-1;}
if ($game==1000+$lines){$game_next=1001;} else {$game_next = $game+1;} 

echo "<div style=\"margin:0; padding:0\">"; 
echo "<a href =\"games/game$game_prev"; echo ".php\"> 
<img src=\"images/go-back.png\" alt=\"next\" class=\"atc-L\"></a>";
echo "<a href =\"games/game$game_next"; echo ".php\"> 
<img src=\"images/go-next.png\" alt=\"next\" class=\"atc-R\"></a>";
echo "</div>";
?>
```

and games.csv is:

```
1231 
1227 
1223 
1222
1185
1166
1163
1013
1007
1002
```

I would like to add and access elements in $list

```
$list = array (1231, 1227, 1223, 1222, 1185, 1166, 1163, 1013, 1007, 1002);
```

I would like to place these numbers in array and sort them and them access them with the php script above. I don't mind if all the numbers are on one line, just as long has php can array them. How can I create such an array and have the php code above scroll forward and backward, say from game1223.php to game1227.php.

Comment: please tell me game 1223.php and game 1227.php are using the same file and you're using htaccess or something to handle the url request. Or at least have one awesome explanation for having each game an individual php file. Your problem is very easy if it is a common file, database driven or something dynamic.

Comment: http://communitychessclub.com/games/game1223.php and http://communitychessclub.com/games/game1227.php are separate files. But the overhead for each file is minimal. Maybe I should look into having the moves ("pgn") portable game notation as a php include from a mysql file. (But I don't know how to do that.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the array `$list` defined then change next/prev lines to:

```
$index = array_search($game, $list);
$max = count($list)-1;
if ($index == 0) {$index_prev = $max;} else {$index_prev = $index-1;}
if ($index == $max) {$index_next = 0;} else {$index_next = $index+1;}
$game_prev = $list[$index_prev];
$game_next = $list[$index_next];
```